# Gigya - Failed - Invalid site domain

Tags: facebook-graph-api, twitter, google-api, gigya

Im trying to create a log-in/register system through Gigya, but can't seem to get it working. I get a couple of errors, with "Failed - Invalid site domain" being the most consistent one.

I've already double-checked my API keys and followed the developer guides on both Gigya and the respective social media.

Anyone know of a solution that I can try?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the Approved URLs on your Site settings section in https://console.gigya.com/

Include the URLs that you would like to use in this domain (we will validate this as part of our security policy). Please use a wildcard (*) to indicate sub-domains, e.g. *.domain.com, or sub directory paths, e.g. www.domain.com/site/*, that use the same configuration.

Read more here: http://developers.gigya.com/010_Developer_Guide/82_Socialize_Setup#Approved_URLs

Comment: I'm trying to implement a shareUiPlugin  GigyaJSExample in localhost and I get the same problem.